# C# Ping.PingCompleted returning the reply

Tags: c#, ping

I am writing an app that needs to store the response times from Ping.SendAsync method, the delegate is currently void :-

```
public delegate void PingCompletedEventHandler(
    object sender,
    PingCompletedEventArgs e
)
```

Would it be possible to change the delegate or define another delegate and attach it to the PingCompleted event ?

Comment: is it not better to push the response times from the handler to a list?
or a variable outside the handler?

Comment: The code that's *calling* the delegate wouldn't *know* of any return value nor be able to do anything with it.

Comment: yup thats the problem, thats why I need to change the delegate so it returns the responce. I thought about using ref, but that is not allowed.

Comment: No, you don't understand. The code that's calling the delegate is code that is part of the `Ping` class. *That* code neither expects a return value nor would it know what to do with one. And you can't change *that* code. (And this is also ignoring that multiple event handlers can be assigned and there's no way for code that causes the event to obtain the possible *multiple* return values, which is why almost all of them are `void`)

Comment: yes, I get that, but wouldnt it be possible to write a delegate in a class that inherits from Ping that would have the reply as the return type and in this class define an event that is triggered when a response is returned from a SendAsync, does that make sense or am I missing something ?